# Convert IBuffer to Byte Array in Java

Tags: java, buffer, arrays

I have used Xuggler tutorial to decode and play video.
I need to see the raw data for every frame.
I have used the method getData as follows:

```
IBuffer img = picture.getData();
```

How to convert IBuffer img to Byte Array in Java?

Thanks

EDIT

I have found the following commands:

```
java.nio.ByteBuffer buffer = img.getByteBuffer(0, bufSize);//bytebuffer

      byte[] bytes = new byte[10]; // Create a byte array
      ByteBuffer buf=buffer.wrap(bytes); // Wrap a byte array into a buffer
      bytes = new byte[buf.remaining()];  // Retrieve bytes between the position and limit
    // (see Putting Bytes into a ByteBuffer)
      buf.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);  // transfer bytes from this buffer into the given destination array
      buf.clear(); // Retrieve all bytes in the buffer
      bytes = new byte[buf.capacity()]; 

      // transfer bytes from this buffer into the given destination array
      buf.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
      System.out.println(bytes);
```

The Output are:

[B@1ccd51b

[B@215eee

[B@1e579dc

[B@14793a8

[B@1082746

.....

They don't have the same length. Is that correct?

I have used:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

to print out the byte array content, but the output look like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

How can I solve this problem?

THANKS

Comment: you print the reference to byte array. it is a just memory address .iterate through the array and print each one. the way you print it is not correct

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I have tried: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes)); and System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(theByte)); but the output is all zero